# Problem uploading a Blazor project in Google App Engine

Tags: c#, google-app-engine, blazor

Is it possible to upload a `Blazor` project to Google App Engine?

I have experimented with Net Core solutions articulated with GAE, DataStore, etc, but when I upload a project `Blazor` Google responds:

> "No valid .NET Core runtime version found for the app or it is not a
>   supported app.".

I am working with Microsoft Net Core 3.1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try publishing using the 'Self-Contained' 'Deployment Mode' option? See: http://blazorhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/4349/Deploying-A-Server-Side-Blazor-Application-To-Azure.aspx

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am trying to upload on Google App Engine. I think what you suggest is for Azure.

Comment: Sorry the only reason I included that link was there is an image that shows the screen that shows where the 'Self-Contained' 'Deployment Mode' option is.

Comment: A self contained deployed project doesn't need the framework, it's why Michael sugest you to take a look.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not getting something:

I have extensions for Google integrated in the IDE. From there you only publish and choose which of your Google projects you want your .net project to go to.

You do not publish from VS, being able to choose the options that you suggest me to see.

Comment: can you share your app.yaml file?

Checking the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/quickstart)  App Engine only support up to Net Core 2.1

Comment: Yes Jorge. I think that must be the problem.

I'll have to wait...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved uploading containers in Google Cloud Run. It is highly recommended for many reasons.